# How to dismiss the download dialog of Firefox using WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, dialog

I write code for my app which when I click a button, the download dialog is popped up. But different from all questions on here, I don't want to save file, I just want to dismiss or close this download dialog.

Is there something like this in Firefox Profile just to dismiss the dialog with a specific file:

```
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk","text/plain");
```

I know there is "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk". I wonder if there is something like "browser.helperApps.neverAsk" only. Thanks

Comment: Clicking a button is a trigger for dialog prompt opening. You can try to apply appropriate `JavaScript` code to disable this trigger before clicking on button

Comment: is a popup appearing and you want to close it? if so, you can use driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();

Comment: @fabersky: I got "org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: No alert is present". Note that this is download dialog from Firefox itself, so i don't know if webdriver treats it like an alert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", true);
```

Refer below:-

http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-download-a-file-with-webdriver

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: I got "org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: No alert is present". Note that this is download dialog from Firefox itself, so i don't know if webdriver treats it like an alert

Comment: I have updated my answer .. I have share one link too .. do refer same

Comment: hello @ShubhamJain, I posted your same answer as a comment yesterday, so please don't be so points-hungry.

Comment: I haven't see that while I have given him the additional answer as well .. can you please look into it ..

Comment: this is not a war @ShubhamJain, this place is meant to cooperate. have a great day

Comment: Thanks guys for helping. A combination of 2 setPreference makes it work, I can proceed to next screen. Thanks again

Comment: welcome .. It feel good to know that your issue is resolve .. :)

Comment: you can mention those two setPreference here so in future if anybody facing the same issue can refer same .. well it's all about contribution